# AWS Lambda timeout on database request

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project running on AWS Lambda with Entity Framework and MySql (Amazon Aurora).

It works perfectly in 99.99% of cases. However, rarely, some queries fail by timeout (30 seconds). The thing that the queries are complicated, and their execution takes about 500-1000ms in most of the cases. But in this rare case, it fails. There is no error message or something else which tells me the cause of such weird behavior. The used memory is not higher than usual.

Probably someone has any ideas on how to find the cause of the problem?

Comment: I would suggest to install this trial https://www.solarwinds.com/database-performance-monitor/integrations/mysql-monitoring and after day of statistic you will see all queries which kills your database.

Comment: I know which query kills the database. I can see it in the logs, and I can run it locally or call the API method with it. And exactly the same query works fine in 99% of cases.

Comment: You always have to expect problems. RDS could have an outage etc. So designing for resilience and recoverability is important. In your case you could retry the request either in your Lambda or through services like SQS. Set a timeout for the request that is reasonable, if it timesout, retry it again. But it might also be a good idea to use SQS and return an error so that SQS retries again etc.

Comment: Oops, this link https://www.solarwinds.com/database-performance-analyzer . Proposing that because it really helped fixing SQL Server issues. Never tried for MySQL, but I hope it works in the same way and supports Aurora.